# ObjectDisposedException on HttpClient

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, async-await, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Universal Project with multiple API calls.
One method refuses to work eventhought my other calls work perfectly like this.
I have tried the `using` keyword thought it would resolve the issue.

The function:

```
public async Task<User> GetNewUser(string user_guid, OAuthTokens OAuth)
{
    String userguidJSON = VALIDJSON_BELIEVE_ME;
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", Encrypt(OAuth.Accesstoken));

        using (HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BASE_URL + URL_USERS + "/data"))
        {
            req.Content = new StringContent(userguidJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            await httpClient.SendAsync(req).ContinueWith(respTask =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()); //Error is thrown ono this line
            });
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public async Task<User> GetNewUser(string user_guid, OAuthTokens OAuth)
{
    String userguidJSON = VALIDJSON_BELIEVE_ME;
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", Encrypt(OAuth.Accesstoken));

        using (HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BASE_URL + URL_USERS + "/data"))
        {
            req.Content = new StringContent(userguidJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
            var result = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.
            Debug.WriteLine(result);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The stacktrace

```
 at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()
   at Roadsmart.Service.RoadsmartService.<GetNewUser>d__2e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Roadsmart.ViewModel.SettingsPageViewModel.<SetNewProfilePicture>d__1e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__3(Object state)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `await` with `ContinueWith`?

Comment: Why are you using `ContinueWith` ? You don't need to use `ContinueWith` when dealing with async/await.

Comment: Note that even though HttpClient implements IDisposable, it is intended to be instantiated once and reused for the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ObjectDisposedException` is thrown because you're disposing the `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpClient` before `req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` finishes.

Note that `req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` is an asynchronous method. You need to wait for it to complete before disposing the `HttpClient`.

Also, you seem to be calling `ReadAsStringAsync` in `req.Content`, shouldn't that be `response.Content`?

```
using (HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BASE_URL + URL_USERS + "/data"))
{
    req.Content = new StringContent(userguidJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();//await it
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
    return null;
}
```

Almost there is no reason to use `ContinueWith` when dealing with async/await. All that is done by the compiler for you.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, but the error is now thrown after var result = ...
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.

Comment: @SeaSharp What is the exception now? Post the stacktrace and your updated code.

Comment: In your code you're awaiting `req.Content`. Shouldn't that be `response.Content`? find my updated answer.

Comment: Aaaaaah! That seemed to have been the culprit. Stupid of me! Have some rep.  Great help!

Answer (score 20):

The actual reason the `ObjectDisposedException` is thrown is because the `HttpClient` disposes the `Content` immediately after a completed request. Have a look at the [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L507).

So if you need to read a `Request`'s content, for example in tests, make sure to read it *before* calling `SendAsync`.

Comment: I hit this problem too. If you try and retry sending the same `Content` twice (following a timeout or similar), you get an ObjectDisposedException

For info, it looks like this has been fixed in the reference source:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L517

(though I'm still seeing the same issue using System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0)

Comment: Same problem using a retry loop with System.Net.Http Version 4.2.0.0

Comment: The original problem seems to have been fixed in .net core 2.0.
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/19082

Answer (score 7):

You are accessing the request Content, not the Response.

This

```
await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
var result = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.
```

should be

```
var response = httpClient.SendAsync(req);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```